# cross domain call using using python and make ajax call to the python to read data

Tags: jquery, python

I am trying to make an ajax request to a python script running in the same webserver. The call happens fine. I am using python to make the cross domain call to return some data back. with .success() i get back all the content of the script file. I could do this PHP quite easily but I am trying to use python for the sake of learning it.

My python looks like this

```
import urllib.request

def main():
    r = urllib.request.urlopen("http://some url").read()
    print(r)

main();
```

My ajax looks like this

```
$('div_something').on('click', function(){

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'html',
                url: "getproduct.py",
            }).done(function(data){
                $('div').html(data);

            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), Python's native support for this isn't friendly.

Edit: I missed the part about success(). Is this what you meant?

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.post("http://some url")
>>> if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print(response.text)
>>> elif response.status_code == 404:
        handle_error()
```

Comment: That doesnt really solve the problem though :-(...I am wondering if I am missing something in the work flow.